# Can't send email from code using Gmail smtp

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send an email using the Gmail smtp server. When I try to send I get

> "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication
>   Required."

I set the credentials in the code so I don't know what I should add. Is there some other property I have to set?

Code:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("noreply@mail.com", "receiver@gmail.com", subject, template);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
client.Port = 587;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");
client.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: try this: client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

Comment: I can't find a AuthenticationMechanisms property on the SmtpClient object

Comment: Don't set UseDefaultCredentials to false after setting the Credentials property. That just sets the credentials to null.

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing everything correctly, this [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) is probably what you need.
Unlike other mail servers, gmail requires more security when third party applications are considered.You should login to your gmail account and allow third party applications to be able to send and receive mails over gmail.